# Multiple use of same file streaming object

Tags: c++, filestreams

I've written the following source code:

```
ifstream leggiFile;
leggiFile.open("Questions.txt",ios::in);

if (!leggiFile.good())
{
  cerr << "\n\n\n\tErrore during file opening Questions.txt\n\n\n" << endl;
}
else
{
    // ...
};

leggiFile.close();
system("pause");
```

Now I'd like to use the same object for working with a second file.

```
leggiFile.open("Answers.txt",ios::in);

i=0;
if(!leggiFile.good())
{
  cerr << "\n\n\n\tError during opening of file answers.txt\n\n\n" << endl;
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Problem: The 2nd time the file cannot be opened and the error message appears. Why?
Could you please suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you've done work on the stream that set one or more of the error flags, such as `eofbit`.

Closing the stream doesn't clear its error flags, you have to do it manually. Call `leggiFile.clear();` after you close it.

Since C++11, this is done automaticaly by `open()`, though. If you're already using a C++11 compiler, your problem is elsewhere (can't say where, you haven't shown enough code).

Comment: Starting with C++11, a successful call to `open` will call `clear`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Didn't know that, thanks. I updated the A to make that clear.

Comment: Dear jrok, Thank You very much. It worked immegiately. I'm using visual C++ 2008 Express version. With that its also possible writing pure C++ code. The version of the C++ compiler I don't know.

Comment: @Uwe_98 Glad it helped. It's common courtesy on Stack Overflow to accept answers that helped you ([How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)). Btw, C++11 is pure C++, it just refers to the specific version of ISO standard for the language. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). Greetz.

Answer (score 0):

Learn `singleton` design pattern for logging or any multiple access  to any file. You can also use Mutex lock so that code will be waited for resources like files. But it is not wise to use same file simultaneously. File can be open for a lyfecycle of code. It is not a issue.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself well. I opened one file, then I closed it and I opened a second file with the same stream. Anyway my problem is solved by using stream.clear(). Thank You.